# unique constraints in django

Tags: django, database, one-to-many

I have a database in django that contains persons and roles. persons has a one-to-many relationship to roles. The problem is that roles doesn't have a unique constraint, for example person adam and david can be artists in roles but django creates two identical artists entries, but I want the same entry, i.e. adam and david should point to one entry. If I add unique to my role field than django says it should be one-to-one. Any ideas?

part of model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

# Create your models here.
# possibillitas models here

class Person(models.Model):

    mail=models.EmailField(default='yourname@gmail.com')
    firstName=models.CharField(max_length=200,default='firstname')
    lastName=models.CharField(max_length=200,default='lastname')
    phoneNumber=PhoneNumberField()
    streetAdress=models.CharField(max_length=200,default='streetAdress')
    zipcode=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=200,default='Göteborg')
    country=models.CharField(max_length=200,default='Sweden')

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.firstName,self.lastName)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('firstName','lastName')

class Role(models.Model):

    role=models.CharField(max_length=200)
#    person=models.ManyToManyField(Person)
    person=models.ForeignKey(Person,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.role

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('role',)

class Name(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    role=models.ForeignKey(Role,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
```

modified admin.py for the answer below:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Role,Alias,Address,Date,Person,Name

from django.conf.urls import url, include

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Role)
admin.site.register(Address)
admin.site.register(Date)
admin.site.register(Name)
admin.site.register(Alias)
admin.site.register(Person)

class AliasInline(admin.TabularInline):

#    model=Role.person.through
    model=Alias
    extra=2

class RoleInline(admin.TabularInline):

#    model=Role.person.through
    model=Role
    extra=2

class NameInline(admin.TabularInline): # nested inlines doesn't work

#class NameInline(admin.ModelAdmin): # nested inlines doesn't work

    model=Name
    extra=3

class PersonInline(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets=[
        (None,{'fields': ['mail','firstName','lastName','phoneNumber','streetAdress','zipcode','city','country']}),
    ]
    inlines = [RoleInline]
    search_fields = ['firstName']
```

Comment: Doesn't it make more sense to make a many-to-many model? What is `name` doing here by the way?

Comment: person can be artist,musician,etc (1-to-M), and every artist and musician can have several names, ex: David -> musician -> (adam the great, adam the singer, etc)

Comment: But then it looks like `Name` is the `through` model of the `Person` and `Role`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through The fact that a person can be an artist, musician, etc. means that it is a `*-M`, but the `*` is how the relation should be quantified in the other direction. Since there can be several persons that are musicians, artists, etc., it looks logical that this is a many-to-many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short**: I think the uniqness constraint should be put on the `role` attribute of the `Role` model, to prevent one creating multiple `Role`s with the same `role` attribute.

## Modeling this as a *many-to-many* relation

It looks to me that you want to use a *many-to-many* relation here, since that means that a `Person` can have *many* `Role`s, and a `Role` can be associated with *many* `Person`s.

You probably should make the `role` field (although perhaps `name` is better here) *unique*, such that one *can not* create two roles with the same name:

```
class Role(models.Model):
    role = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(Person, related_name='roles')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.role

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('role',)
```

We can than create two `Person`s that are both artists like:

```
role_artist, __ = Role.objects.get_or_create(role='artist')

adam = Person.objects.create(firstName='Adam')
david = Person.objects.create(firstName='David')

adam.roles.add(role_artist)
david.roles.add(role_artist)
```

## `Name` as a *through* model

The `Name` model you define, seems to work as a `Through` model: it adds extra data to the relation. For example a person may have two `Name`s: one as a singer and one as a moviestar. This is typically the usecase of a [**`through`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) where one can encode extra data in the relation, although it might be better to name this `Alias` (or at least a more descriptive name).

We can remodel this as:

```
class Role(models.Model):
    role = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Alias', related_name='roles')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.role

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('role',)

class Alias(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
```

We can then make two `Person`s `adam` and `david` that are both artists, and each with their artist name:

```
role_artist, __ = Role.objects.get_or_create(role='artist')

adam = Person.objects.create(firstName='Adam')
david = Person.objects.create(firstName='David')

Alias.objects.create(name='Adam the magician', role=role_artist, person=adam)
Alias.objects.create(name='David the lion tamer', role=role_artist, person=david)
```

it is even possible that a `Person` has multiple `Alias`ses, for the same role.

## Concluding remarks

> **Note**: according to [**PEP 8**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) the naming convention is that attributes are lowercase and words are separated with underscores. So that means that it should be `first_name` instead of `firstName`.

Comment: ok, I tried it but got: sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: artdb_role.role
and a large error trace... Will look into it

Comment: @JonasFredriksson: that is likely because there are already two `Role` objects in your database with the same `role`. So you will need to migitate that first.

Comment: I flush my database, but the problem remains. I think it is in the admin.py: please look at my admin.py above

Comment: ok, no errors anymore,  I just dropped the whole database and removed all migrations. thanks